# How to display text on icon in native script angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am implementing shopping cart app with native script angular. I want to display total items on the cart icon.
Right now am able to show cart icon on the action bar. But i want to show total items selected on the cart icon.
[how to show text on icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqdUL.png)

Can some one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CustomView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/action-bar#styling), may be with a grid layout with an image and label.

Comment: thanks It worked almost.. icon with label.. trying display this label on top of the icon by setting margin and padding..Its not working.. But i will try.